# In React Final Form, providing initialValues to nested fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-final-form

I'm working with React Final Form, and for some reason, when I try to pass initial values to its `initialValues` prop, it doesn't work if the keys I use are in the format `'key6.value'` - the `Field` with that name stays empty. It does, however, work if the format doesn't have the . in the middle, e.g. `'key6value'`.

Why doesn't initialValues work for these nested fields (fields with names that have the .)? And what can I do to make it pass the `initialValues`?

I've tested this thoroughly to make sure I identified the issue, and the only difference between having the Fields populate and not has been the . in their `name` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to initialize with the actual nested structure. Not like this:

```
{
  'key5.value': 'init value' // ❌
  ...
}
```

Like this:

```
{
  key5: {
    value: 'init value' // ✅
  }
  ...
}
```

Does that help?