# how to show initial values for FieldArray

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, react-final-form-arrays

I have ann app that users go and add as many text-fields as they want and enter their cars' names (I did it easily via FieldArray).

Now the problem is I need an Edit page where users go and see all the cars that they had entered in add page and be able to edit them. I need to render the FieldArray again and use something like InitialValues.

**So if the user created, for instance, 5 cars in the Add page, when he/she goes to the Edit page I want to see 5 inputs there created via FieldArray with the cars' names.**
How to do that?

Comment: What have you tried? [have you looked around for a possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52012228/2733506)?

Comment: @JohnRuddell   yes I tried initialValues but it didn't work or i don't know how to it correctly for fieldArrays.

Comment: you mean like this example from their docs? https://codesandbox.io/s/91w9ro3x9o

Comment: @JohnRuddell  yes the same as that, it feels my regular fields but not the FieldArray :(

Comment: @JohnRuddell I added more info into the question :)

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. So can you use the render prop on the `FieldArray` to fill in the initial value. [**Heres an example of that**](https://codesandbox.io/s/j7o525yn23) :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell   I was just having a silly silly typo there!!! making things not working! thanks indeed for your time and help you saved me lots of time, much appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to initialize the form via `initialValues` with the array of car names. Something like...

```
// load values from server
const values = {
  cars: [
    'Alex', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'Dennis', 'Erik'
  ]
}

...

<Form onSubmit={whatever} initialValues={values}>
  {({ handleSubmit }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      // fields here, just like you did on "add" page
    </form>
  )}
</Form>
```

Comment: thanks, Erik, It's very nice of you to help us directly. I was using your redux-form for a while and now react-final-form. I introduced it to my friend's company and now they all moved to it :))) thanks for the great work.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the praise! 